# How to read emails with Python and Gmail API

Tags: python, gmail, gmail-api

I want to get unread emails from my inbox with python code.
I set up google developer account, I made an app (I set it to DESKTOP) and I downloaded credentials.

```
{"installed":{"client_id":"xxx",
              "project_id":"xxx",
              "auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
              "token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
              "auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
              "client_secret":"xxx",
              "redirect_uris":["http://localhost"]
              }
}
```

This is the code that I have:

```
import os
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file(os.path.expanduser('gmail_credencials.json'), ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'])
service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
print(service)
messages = service.users().messages()
print(messages)
```

But I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: Authorized user info was not in the expected format, missing fields refresh_token, client_secret, client_id.
```

I have `client_secret` and `client_id`, but I do not have a clue where should I get `refresh_token`.

Does anyone else has the experience with this error?

Answer (score 0):

The error message you are facing is related to the missing `token.json` file. This file is created automatically using the `credentials.json` file (In your case I think it is called `gmail_credencials.json` based on your code snippet.)

So instead of calling the `credentials.json` file as your are doing in this part of the code:

```
creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file(
              os.path.expanduser('gmail_credencials.json'), 
              ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']
          )
```

You need to call the token file that is created after the authorization flow is completed.  The `authorization flow` is this part of the sample below:

```
 creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())
```

Once the code is created, and stored. You can create the creds (the credentials use for building the services) like this:

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']

creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
```

The scopes, I add them as variables, so it will be easier to change them if necessary.

*Note: You can either rename your credential file to `credentials.json` or you can replace the sample code with the name of your JSON file.*

This is a sample code based on the Google Documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python). It has an example about the refresh token on it. I'm also [listing](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list) the files emails that have the label `UNREAD`. After that, I [get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/get) the emails with the IDs of  the list, and decode the messages payload using base64. Take in consideration that this is just a sample.

The code does the following:

1. Review if the Token is available or does the refresh token process in case the current Token is not valid.
2. List all the emails that are labeled as `UNREAD`.
3. Using the message ID that we got from the list method and the information of the email.
4. Decode the email information from `base64` to `ASCII`.
5. Get the payload of the message (since the Google messages are multipart).
6. Print the `plain text` and the `html` of the email.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
import email
import base64 #add Base64
import time 

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']


def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Gmail API.
    Lists the user's Gmail labels.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())
            
        #Filter and get the IDs of the message I need. 
        #I'm just filtering messages that have the label "UNREAD"

    try:
        service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
        search_id = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', labelIds="UNREAD").execute()
        number_result = search_id['resultSizeEstimate']

        final_list = [] # empty array, all the messages ID will be listed here
        
        # review if the search is empty or not
        # if it has messages on it, It will enter the for

        if number_result>0:
            message_ids = search_id['messages']

            for ids in message_ids:
                final_list.append(ids['id'])
                # call the function that will call the body of the message
                get_message(service, ids['id'] )
                
            return final_list
        
        # If there are not messages with those criterias 
        #The message 'There were 0 results for that search string' will be printed. 

        else:
            print('There were 0 results for that search string')
            return ""

    except HttpError as error:
        # TODO(developer) - Handle errors from gmail API.
        print(f'An error occurred: {error}')
        
        
        #new function to get the body of the message, and decode the message

def get_message(service, msg_id):

    try:
        message_list=service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=msg_id, format='raw').execute()

        msg_raw = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(message_list['raw'].encode('ASCII'))

        msg_str = email.message_from_bytes(msg_raw)

        content_types = msg_str.get_content_maintype()
        
        #how it will work when is a multipart or plain text

        if content_types == 'multipart':
            part1, part2 = msg_str.get_payload()
            print("This is the message body, html:")
            print(part1.get_payload())
            return part1.get_payload()
        else:
            print("This is the message body plain text:")
            print(msg_str.get_payload())
            return msg_str.get_payload()


    except HttpError as error:
        # TODO(developer) - Handle errors from gmail API.
        print(f'An error occurred: {error}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

**Reference:**

- [Method: users.messages.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list)
- [Method: users.messages.get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/get)
- [Format](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/Format)
- [Google Documentation "Python quickstart"](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python)
- [base64 Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html)
- [Get an OAuth2 Refresh Token and Configure Your Client](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/first-call/refresh-token#python)

Comment: googleapiclient dependency is dead.